# Comparing doubles using ULPs (Units in the last place)

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, floating-point-precision, emscripten

I have succeeded in writing an Ulps based function that compares two doubles for equality. According to [this page](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm), the comparison can be made using a combination of absolute and relative epsilon or using integers (Ulps).

I have made both epsilon based and Ulps based functions. This is the epsilon based function:

```
var IsAlmostEqual_Epsilon = function(a, b)
{
  if (a == b) return true;
  var diff = Math.abs(a - b);
  if (diff < 4.94065645841247E-320) return true;
  a = Math.abs(a);
  b = Math.abs(b);
  var smallest = (b < a) ? b : a;
  return diff < smallest * 1e-12;
}
```

And this is the Ulps based (`DoubleToInt64Bits`, `subtract`, `negate` and `lessthan` functions are in the below mentioned JSBIN):

```
var IsAlmostEqual_Ulps = function(A, B)
{
  if (A==B) return true;
  DoubleToInt64Bits(A, aInt);
  if(aInt.hi < 0) aInt = subtract(Int64_MinValue, aInt);
  DoubleToInt64Bits(B, bInt);
  if(bInt.hi < 0) bInt = subtract(Int64_MinValue, bInt);
  var sub = subtract(aInt, bInt);
  if (sub.hi < 0) sub = negate(sub);
  if (lessthan(sub, maxUlps)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

According to [Bruce Dawson](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) the Ulps based is preferred. `IsAlmostEqual_Ulps` is working ok according to test base of 83 cases, but the function is pretty slow. It takes about 700-900 ms to complete the test base ([JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uxazIPeK/4)) when executed as a standalone html (outside JSBIN). Epsilon based `IsAlmostEqual_Epsilon` takes only about 100 ms.

**Is there anything that can be done to speedup `IsAlmostEqual_Ulps` function?** You can propose also a completely different solution or some fixings to my code.

I have tested already the inlining everything, but it cuts the time only about 5-10%. I'm hunting something like 50-80% improvement in execution time. 100-500% improvement would be fine, but it may be only a dream.

`right_answers` in the JSBIN code are got using C# `IsAlmostEqual` function (see at the top of JSBIN code). Both above functions give the same results in all 83 cases.

---

EDIT:

C++ version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/code/HEAD/tree/sandbox/clipper.cpp):

```
bool IsAlmostEqual(double A, double B)
{
    //http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm
    long long aInt = reinterpret_cast<long long&>(A);
    if (aInt < 0) aInt = -9223372036854775808LL - aInt;
    long long bInt = reinterpret_cast<long long&>(B);
    if (bInt < 0) bInt = -9223372036854775808LL - bInt;
    return (std::abs(aInt - bInt) <= 10000);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for typed buffer views:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView

Comment: Could you make a buffered view version?

Comment: @FabioBeltramini: ... and type it as a new answer. The current only one answer doesn't provide solution in this case.

Comment: I also tried to now optimize the new object creation & assignment out of your subtraction function. See http://jsbin.com/IWoyIDO/3/edit
In doing so, I also noticed your negate function probably is not working as you expect it to. Check the comment I left in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Although your suggestion (accepted answer) is a good speedup, it is still not well suitable for realtime usage (eg. in editor). I tested in Safari. My Ulps function takes 2533 ms, yours takes 1541 ms and Epsilon-based takes 99 ms. I think that we have to wait native Javascript 64-bit integers to get acceptable speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since my original "insight" wasn't too helpful, here's another answer, that simply takes your existing functions and reorganizes them to minimize repetitive object constructor calls:

```
var ULPS2 = function(){
  var buf2 = new ArrayBuffer(8);
  var dataView2A = new DataView(buf2);
  var dataView2B = new DataView(buf2);
  var aInt=new Int64(0, 0), bInt=new Int64(0, 0);
  var sub;

  this.IsAlmostEqual=function(A,B){
    if (A==B) return true;
    dataView2A.setFloat64(0, A);
    aInt.lo = dataView2A.getInt32(4) | 0;
    aInt.hi = dataView2A.getInt32(0) | 0;
    dataView2B.setFloat64(0, B);
    bInt.lo = dataView2B.getInt32(4) | 0;
    bInt.hi = dataView2B.getInt32(0) | 0;

    if(aInt.hi < 0) aInt = subtract(Int64_MinValue, aInt);

    if(bInt.hi < 0) bInt = subtract(Int64_MinValue, bInt);
    sub = subtract(aInt, bInt);
    if (sub.hi < 0) sub = negate(sub);
    if (lessthan(sub, maxUlps)) return true;
    return false;
  }

}
var Ulps2=new ULPS2();
```

Based on a test in Chrome and Firefox at http://jsbin.com/IWoyIDO/2/ , it appears to yield a 30%-50% improvement. Not phenomenal, but at least better than the 5-10% improvement you were originally mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way that would be faster for sure (currently as fast as 1.5 times the speed of native code), which would be to use [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/), a highly optimizable subset of Javascript.

This is the [unreal gaming engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/) running on it, to have an idea of the type of performance (takes a bit to load but runs very smoothly, use firefox or chrome).

The way it works is that you take your code and write in a statically typed language: C or C++. Then compile it into bytecode of the LLVM C++ virtual machine. Then use the [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) compiler to generate asm.js Javascript code.

If the browser does not detect and optimize asm.js, it runs it as Javascript. If the browser (like latest versions of Chrome/Firefox) detects asm.js, you will have a near native performance.

Check the [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/asmjs-javascript-compile-target/) of John Resig (creator of jQuery) about it. You can't get faster than that in a browser these days, and it keeps getting faster (see Mozilla team blog post [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/12/gap-between-asm-js-and-native-performance-gets-even-narrower-with-float32-optimizations/)).

Comment: Could you provide asm.js compiled version of IsAlmostEqual_Ulps function? I added the C++ function at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I won't be able to in the near future, altough it sounds like a fun experiment. Basically you use clang to compile it to LLVM bytecode, and emscripten takes that and generates the asm.js javascript. Have a look at this tutorial https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial all the steps are detailed there, also here is how to call this from javascript https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code. The code would run faster for sure, how much the only way to know is to try it out. If you try it out can you report back on your findings?

Comment: Sounds rather complicated for my brains currently. I added emscripten and c++ tags, so hopefully someone who have experience of using the proposed technique have time to answer.

Comment: I tried emscripten, but there appeared an error: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21489197/1691517.

Comment: I succeeded (AFAIK) in compiling, but it returns incorrect value in 36% of cases and is significantly slower than handcoded functions and generates 620x bigger file than original C++. So Emscripten seems not to be an option here. The comparison is here: http://jsbin.com/uxazIPeK/9.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic gist of how to improve the performance using new browser functionality of typed arrays. Note that because no native 64-bit int view is provided, you will have to rework the logic on your own based on 2 32-bit ints, and ensure endianness does not affect the calculation on different systems. I am just trying to address the javascript speed portion of the problem, not be an expert on float encoding. Hopefully this is clear:

```
var IsAlmostEqual_Ulps = function(A, B)
{
  var smallBufferA = new ArrayBuffer(8); //8 bytes = 64bits
  var viewAsDoubleA = new Float64Array(smallBufferA); //byteOffset=0, length=8 optional
  var viewAsIntA = new Int32Array(smallBufferA); //byteOffset=0, length=8 optional
  viewAsDoubleA.set([A]);
  console.log(viewAsIntA);
  var smallBufferB = new ArrayBuffer(8); //8 bytes = 64bits
  var viewAsDoubleB = new Float64Array(smallBufferB); //byteOffset=0, length=8 optional
  var viewAsIntB = new Int32Array(smallBufferB); //byteOffset=0, length=8 optional
  viewAsDoubleB.set([B]);
  console.log(viewAsIntB);
  //The logic below is just illustrative and may not be right. Please test & adjust
  var A_lo=viewAsIntA[1];
  var B_lo=viewAsIntB[1];
  var A_hi=viewAsIntA[0];
  var B_hi=viewAsIntB[0];
  if(A_hi<0){A_hi=Int32_MinValue-A_hi;}
  if(A_hi<0){A_hi=Int32_MinValue-A_hi;}
  //You'll have to rewrite these slightly, I think you know how
  var sub = subtract(viewAsIntA, viewAsIntB); 
  if (sub.hi < 0) sub = negate(sub);
  if (lessthan(sub, maxUlps)) return true;
}
```

For example, if you called `IsAlmostEqual_Ulps(3.14159,3.14159001)`, you would get logged in your console:

```
[-266631570, 1074340345]
[-244113572, 1074340345]
```

That should get you the biggest performance gains. If you want to make it even faster, you should reuse existing buffers (from the global scope or a closure) between function calls to not incur the constructor overhead and the garbage collection.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that some browsers will not support this. You should to feature testing to define this function accordingly as the above, or the slower version if typed arrays are not available in that browser.

Comment: Thanks. Why there is two times this: `if(A_hi<0){A_hi=Int32_MinValue-A_hi;}`? And why Int32_MinValue? It should be Int64_MinValue?

Comment: The provided solution seems not to be complete. Could you provide a complete solution? I have 22 hours time to award the bounty.

Comment: As I mentioned Javascript has no 64 bit integer type to expose, so the results of the "Int32Array" buffer view is a pair of 32 bit ints. As I mentioned, the details of interpreting these 2 ints is outside the scope of my knowledge. The insight here is that we are using a faster method to convert the floats into integers, and will be using integers that are within Javascript's native types, so we will be able to do the sub and negate functions with a few fast basic arithmetic operators.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be faster than my original function. Sub and negate functions are still not possible using basic arithmetic operators. Bitwise operators are still needed in subtract.

Comment: This techique seems not to be a speed improvement, in fact it is many times slower than original. See: http://jsbin.com/IWoyIDO/1/edit (`IsAlmostEqual_Ulps2()`).

Comment: I'm sorry, the first comment I made was not originally intended as an answer in and of itself, just a general observation that the most efficient way to access the data from the double was using a buffer view. However, it seems your DoubleToInt64Bits was already using a buffer view... then, when you asked for a full answer, I neglected to check that you were not already implementing this technique.